# What is the current state of text-only compression algorithms?

Tags: compression, lossless-compression, text-compression

In honor of the [Hutter Prize](http://prize.hutter1.net/), 
what are the top algorithms (and a quick description of each) for text compression?

Note: The intent of this question is to get a description of compression algorithms, not of compression programs.

Comment: I saw once an (mock) article proposing a lossy compression of text, with excellent performance (in size!)... Was funny.

Comment: @PhiLho heh, that's essentially what Summly did :) http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/03/25/yahoo_buys_summly/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The boundary-pushing compressors combine algorithms for insane results. Common algorithms include:

- The [Burrows-Wheeler Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows-Wheeler_transform) and [here](http://marknelson.us/1996/09/01/bwt/) - shuffle characters (or other bit blocks) with a predictable algorithm to increase repeated blocks which makes the source easier to compress. Decompression occurs as normal and the result is un-shuffled with the reverse transform. Note: BWT alone doesn't actually compress anything. It just makes the source easier to compress.
- [Prediction by Partial Matching (PPM)](http://books.google.com/books?id=ChSOjgiY84YC&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=Prediction+by+Partial+Match+PPM&source=web&ots=HIq05xfhjB&sig=b5JSuIz9D9C7yJJCwLcoTL2ECnM&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=3&ct=result) - an evolution of [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) where the prediction model(context) is created by crunching statistics about the source versus using static probabilities. Even though its roots are in arithmetic coding, the result can be represented with Huffman encoding or a dictionary as well as arithmetic coding.
- Context Mixing - Arithmetic coding uses a static context for prediction, PPM dynamically chooses a single context, Context Mixing uses many contexts and weighs their results. PAQ uses context mixing. [Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ#Algorithm) a high-level overview.
- [Dynamic Markov Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Markov_Compression) - related to PPM but uses bit-level contexts versus byte or longer.
- In addition, the Hutter prize contestants may replace common text with small-byte entries from external dictionaries and differentiate upper and lower case text with a special symbol versus using two distinct entries. That's why they're so good at compressing text (especially ASCII text) and not as valuable for general compression.

[Maximum Compression](http://www.maximumcompression.com/index.php) is a pretty cool text and general compression benchmark site. Matt Mahoney publishes another [benchmark](http://www.cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/compression/text.html). Mahoney's may be of particular interest because it lists the primary algorithm used per entry.

Comment: Are there algorithms that compress text and give me back text (not binary)?

Comment: Pied Piper compression was not discovered when this list was created!

Comment: I wonder how use of gpt3 AI in prediction of next token part might improve on the best results until now . Can it beat existing best results so far . Let’s assume we don’t care for speed and want max compression, like for long term text archival purposes

Comment: @sktguha: the available papers and research (sorry, no citations yet) points to AI based compression being much, much, much better than anything else out there. However, there is one very severe drawback: AI based compression is usually at least 300 times slower. That's a no go for a lot of use cases.

Answer (score 8):

There's always [lzip](http://web.archive.org/web/20050514074112/lzip.sourceforge.net/).

All kidding aside:

- Where compatibility is a concern, PKZIP (`DEFLATE` algorithm) still wins.
- bzip2 is the best compromise between being enjoying a relatively broad install base and a rather good compression ratio, but requires a separate archiver.
- [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/) (`LZMA` algorithm) compresses very well and is available for under the LGPL. Few operating systems ship with built-in support, however.
- [rzip](http://rzip.samba.org/) is a variant of bzip2 that in my opinion deserves more attention. It could be particularly interesting for huge log files that need long-term archiving. It also requires a separate archiver.

Comment: These come no where near PAQ and several other text-only compression algorithms (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ)

Comment: @BrianR.Bondy: you're right, `zpaq` compressed an order of magnitude smaller than PKZIP. See below (yes, it's a tool, but some people come here looking for exactly that)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use PAQ as a program, you can install the `zpaq` package on debian-based systems. Usage is (see also `man zpaq`)

```
zpaq c archivename.zpaq file1 file2 file3
```

Compression was to about **1/10th of a zip file's size**. (1.9M vs 15M)